# The searchview goes upwards behind the toolbar when keyboard opens how to show the search view when typing?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, searchview

When i am trying to type in searchview the searchview goes upwards behind the toolbar and is not visible

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <data>
    <variable name="homeviewmodel" type="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.HomeViewModel"/>
   </data>
 
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context=".ui.homepage.searchfoodsdir.SearchFoods">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/serchcooksfoods"
    android:layout_width="319dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#1BF1F1"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.183" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/searchfoodslist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="501dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serchcooksfoods" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

and the searchview cant be visible how to make searchview visible and working when i am typing

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the activity tag in the manifest file

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"